# Listener on (WebDAV) directory?

Tags: directory, listener, webdav

I'm searching for a way to know when a file of a directory is modify, create or delete.

Thanks for any interest to my problem!

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about push notifications. FYI, there's some work in the CalConnect group on push notifications for Caldav which is intended to be useful for general webdav. So hopefully we'll have this soon!

Comment: I will follow this with attention :  it's exactly what I'm waiting for! Thank you

Comment: FYI - http://www.calconnect.org/tc-push.shtml

Comment: And some recent discussion - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-dist-auth/2014AprJun/0007.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal way to do this. Some servers *may* provide facilities to do this, but it highly depends on which server you're running.

So lacking that, the only universal thing you can do is issue PROPFIND requests every x seconds and see if something changed.

Comment: Thanks, it was what I thinking, too bad. I will see forward my server. Bye